Cannot pass a kwargs into `torch.onnx.export` arguments in Pytorch ONNX
I want to export a pytorch model into onnx format. Here is model:
from transformers import AutoProcessor, PaliGemmaForConditionalGeneration, BitsAndBytesConfig

model_id = "google/paligemma-3b-mix-224"

quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_8bit=True)

model = PaliGemmaForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(
    model_id, quantization_config=quantization_config
).eval()
processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(model_id)

And my exporting onnx code is:
torch.onnx.export(
    model,
    (input_ids, attention_mask, pixel_values),
    "model.onnx",
    input_names=['input_ids', 'attention_mask', 'pixel_values'],
    output_names=['output']
)

The above code throws this error:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/accelerate/hooks.py in new_forward(module, *args, **kwargs)
    164                 output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
    165         else:
--> 166             output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
    167         return module._hf_hook.post_forward(module, output)
    168 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/siglip/modeling_siglip.py in forward(self, pixel_values, interpolate_pos_encoding)
    302 
    303     def forward(self, pixel_values: torch.FloatTensor, interpolate_pos_encoding=False) -> torch.Tensor:
--> 304         _, _, height, width = pixel_values.shape
    305         patch_embeds = self.patch_embedding(pixel_values)  # shape = [*, width, grid, grid]
    306         embeddings = patch_embeds.flatten(2).transpose(1, 2)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)

I have tried couple of solution, I think this is because when passing input to onnx, it equivalent to (This code throw the same above error):
model(input_ids, attention_mask, pixel_values)

However, the correct way to pass input to model is using kwargs
model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, pixel_values=pixel_values)

How can I passed the keywords into onnx exporter, or is there any better approarch to export onnx format?
